# PHP Curl to C# Webclient/HTTPRequest

Tags: c#, php, curl

I'm trying to convert the following to C# without much luck.

```
<?php
$data = '<xml>my xml request here</xml>';
$tuCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://myendpoint");
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml","SOAPAction: \"/soap/action/query\"", "Content-length: ".strlen($data)));
```

Below is what I've come up with but I'm not receiving the expected result. Is there something I'm simply missing in my C# ?

```
    using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var data = new NameValueCollection();
        data.Add("", "my xml here");

        var result = client.UploadValues("my endpoint here", data);

        var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
    }
```

Comment: You didn't send any headers.  Your conversion seems to be incomplete.

Comment: I've tried adding the following:                client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml");
                client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "/soap/action/query");
                client.Headers.Add("Content-length", document.InnerXml.Length.ToString());

Comment: My main question is why isn't there a "key" for the $data attribute. Key/Value dictionary

Comment: This is a clearer example of what I'm trying to convert: http://www.phpmoot.com/php-dhl-shipping-rate/

Comment: FYI I figured this out http://vh4u.blogspot.com/2015/02/using-dhl-web-services-in-your-net.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI I figured this out with the following code snippet:

```
    public static string POST(string url, string requestXML)
    {
        WebRequest webReq = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        webReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webReq.Method = "POST";

        using (var stream = webReq.GetRequestStream())
        {
            var arrBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXML);
            stream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }

        WebResponse webResp = webReq.GetResponse();
        var respStream = webResp.GetResponseStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(respStream, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        string strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        respStream.Close();

        return strResponse;
    }
```

http://vh4u.blogspot.com/2015/02/using-dhl-web-services-in-your-net.html